# Cannot move through suggestion list of react material ui AutoComplete via arrow keys

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [AutoComplete](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete) for a typeahead.

```
`<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
                    <AutoComplete id="#parkingSuggestion" onUpdateInput={this.onUpdateInputParkingSuggestion}
                                  dataSource={this.props.parkingAutoComplete}
                                  onNewRequest={this.onNewRequestParkingSuggestion} maxSearchResults={20}
                                  fullWidth={true} dataSourceConfig={dataConfiguration}
                                  filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}/>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
```

When the suggestion list is populated, on pressing the down key, the first item of the suggestion list is highlighted, however the second item is not selected on pressing the down key again. The list items can be selected by clicking on them but pressing enter has no effect.

The material-ui version is **0.15.4**

Comment: please create a fiddle/demo showing your problem

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Also, what version of material-ui are you using?

Comment: @CaseyC what part of the code do you want to see, the functions defined in the props work fine. The drop down doesn't work